# error in asp.net when building

Tags: asp.net

The type 'gp_ss_statement_run2' already contains a definition for 'some name'

Has anyone ever got this error?  If so how do you fix it?

This happens when we try to build.

Comment: Please be more specific. Tell us what references you have in the project, if possible more details about the error.

Comment: unfortunately I can't because of where I work.

Answer (score 1):

Clear out your bin directory, then re-publish your web application.  If that doesn't work then you will need to [clear your ASP.NET Temp files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx).

If you still get this error, then you have something declaring more than once with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer -- now to conveince the other guys it is a good idea to clear out the temp folder.